# Relation between Constant throughput timer, transactions per sec and throughput in summary report

Tags: jmeter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM7zw.png)I am setting a test plan where I need to set a load of 15 request per min for my web service. How can I do so?

I tried set up the test plan as below:
No. of threads: 20
Ramp up period:10
Duration: 120 seconds
Constant throughput timer is set under thread with values:
Target throughput: 15
Calculated throughput: All Active threads

Result:
Under summary report it showed throughput value as 33.9/min. I am not getting how this exceed 15/min set under constant throughput timer.
Also, under transactions per sec graph, the value in intervals touch as 2,3,1,....and 20 in end.

I am not able to understand the relation between constant throughput timer, Throughput under summary report and transactions per sec graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the case Constant Throughput Timer is not "precise" enough, given you need to limit JMeter's throughput to 15 requests/minute assuming 20 threads it's better to consider [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) which has lower granularity therefore it's being applied immediately and gives exact throughput figures comparing to the Constant Throughput Timer / [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer).

The relevant configuration would be:

[image]

You can install Throughput Shaping Timer plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager):

[image]

Comment: :I used Throughput shaping timer with values as 0.5 for 120 secs. Throughput now coming under my summary report is 11.5/min, max:502, min:55. I guess I would need to increase no. of threads to achieve target of 15/min. I came across this formula to calculate desired RPS RPS * <max response time> / 1000. Where should I bring this max response time value from? Also, does limiting the throughput through shaping timer affect the actual response time of my request?Like if I change from 15/min to 50/min, surely the numbers in summary report will change.So how to get the actual response time?

Comment: I came across this formula to calculate desired RPS RPS * <max response time> / 1000. In my case would it be : (0.25*60*502)/1000=7.53?

Comment: Correction: (0.25*1000*502)/1000=125.5. Should it be passed under no. of threads?